# In need of Angular pre-observable

Tags: angular, design-patterns, rxjs, observable

I am currently using rxjs/Subject Observable object in several locations in my app.  I like the way that it works because you can just add more subscribers to the service any time you want and you don't have to modify any other component that sends messages, however i have a new use case that i don't think this object can handle and I am wondering if there is another object that does what i need.

The scenario is this:

I have one component that needs to import the object and send a message in the same way that rxjs/Subject does it, I have another component that needs to subscribe to messages and in most cases it will respond to them in real time, however on app load this component is loaded after the first one and so therefore misses the first message (which is sent immediately when the first component is loaded)

Is there such a design pattern where messages can be queued up and read by observers at a later point?

I'm sure i could make this myself, but i'd rather not re-invent the wheel if i don't have to.

Comment: You can use a ReplaySubject if you want to »cache« a specific number of values. But that will replay the last `n` items to all subscriptions, no matter when they occur.

Comment: Not bad but i think the BehaviorSubject is what i'm looking for in this particular case,  thanks.

Comment: In the sense of replaying values ReplaySubject(1) and BehaviorSubject are exactly the same, but the latter also has an initial value. So frankly I don't see how your question is better answered by BehaviorSubject than ReplaySubject.

Comment: @DallasCaley I agree with Ingo Bürk. When you mentioned that messages (values) need to be "queued up" I thought ReplaySubject (or shareReplay) would be better solution as you can replay (queue up) n number of values

Comment: The reason I choose Behavior subject is because in my case the message that I'm sending sets the initial state of the child component (the child component is an accordion where some of the rows might be expanded.  the message is a csv of the expanded row ids) So i actually don't care about anything but the most recent message.  Sorry, my use case wasn't completely spelled out in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html) extends Subject and provides every subscriber the latest value, no matter when they subscribe.